# AttributeError: module 'google' has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, google-api, anaconda, google-api-client

I use jupyter notebook to run code. I created two environment in anaconda,one is python 2.7 ,the other is 3.5 version (which I mainly use). So I try to use the following link to install google api `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-api-python-client` ,it seems like google package already installed.but when I tried the following code,there is an error message.

```
import google
In [5]:

google.search()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-113947656c70> in <module>()
----> 1 google.search

AttributeError: module 'google' has no attribute 'search'
```

Do I run the wrong direction?

Comment: I don't see the search package in the documentation. What documentation are you referring to that shows this?

Comment: I want to use google API to extract website from google ,so I need to use ```google.search()``` to extract.So I downloaded the wrong module? Maybe this one? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google .I also try this one https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API ,but it still does not work

Comment: Yeah the module you linked in the original post is to use the official google API. You'll need to get a developer API key and read the docs. The other two you mention in the comments use libraries to do google searches using the requests library and parse the results using BeautifulSoup so they don't need the API key. If all you need is something simple to do straightforward google search results I would use one of these.